# VSCode unable to find method on fully functional code

Tags: java

On Geany and my friend's computer this code works. But on my VSCode app it gives the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
> The method fuelNeeded(int) is undefined for the type Vehicle
> The method fuelNeeded(int) is undefined for the type Vehicle
> at AddParamVehicle.main(AddParamVehicle.java:18)

I would like to understand why this happens and how to fix it. Thanks.
Edited after I updated to JDK 19, still giving same error.

```
public class AddParamVehicle {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Vehicle minivan = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle sportscar = new Vehicle();
        double gallons;
        int dist = 252;

        // assign values to fields in  minivan
        minivan.passengers = 7;
        minivan.fuelcap =16;
        minivan.mpg = 21;

        //assign vlaues to fields in sportscar
        sportscar.passengers = 2;
        sportscar.fuelcap = 14;
        sportscar.mpg = 12;

        gallons = minivan.fuelNeeded (dist);

        System.out.println("To go " + dist + " miles minivan needs " + gallons + " gallons of fuel.");
        
        gallons = sportscar.fuelNeeded (dist);

        System.out.println("To go " + dist + " miles sportscar needs " + gallons + " gallons of fuel.");
        
    }
    
}

 class Vehicle{
    int passengers;
    int fuelcap;
    int mpg;

    // return the range
   public int range() {
        return fuelcap * mpg;
    }

    // compute fuel needed for a given distance
    public double fuelNeeded (int miles) {
        return (double) miles / mpg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you using an old version of the code

Comment: Your code works for me in VSCode 1.74.2 and JDK 19.

Comment: I'm also using VSCode 1.74.2 and just upgraded to JDK 19. Still doesn't work for me. Geany does though.

Comment: Then I would say that the problem is not with your code but rather with how you have configured your VSCode.

Comment: I can also run your code with no problems: VS Code 1.74.2, Java 18.0.2 and 19.0.1. It compiles and runs just fine manually using `javac` and `java`, as well. You must not be running what you think you're running and/or there's something wrong with your configuration.

Comment: Check your imports! This problem can be caused by importing another `Vehicle` class which does not contain a `fuelNeeded ` method.

Answer (score 0):

checking your java version that I think it's old.

Comment: I have jdk 17 installed. Is that the recommended one?

Comment: @Cookies Java 17.X.X is good as it's an LTS version, though the latest release is 19.0.1. Regardless, I'm not sure how old of a Java version you'd have to be using for your code not to compile and run. Your code looks compatible with Java 8. It's probably compatible with Java 7, 6, and 5, if not even older (though I've only ever used Java 8 or above, so I there could be some issue that I'm missing). The point being, however, that I doubt your problem is with the version of Java you're using.